# How to translate "the finer points of the Pythagorean theorem" into german?

Tags: english-to-german

"A math tutor schooled me in the finer points of the Pythagorean theorem"

Is "Ein Mathematiklehrer brachte mir die Feinheiten im Satz des Pythagoras bei" a good translation? Is there a better one?

Comment: You should provide more context to answer the question. In the present form I vote to close it.

Comment: Simple translation or proofreading requests are considered off-topic here. It would help if you could narrow the issue down to a specific phrase that's confusing you. If you just want a translation, machine translators such as Google Translate and Deepl usually do a good job (though still not perfect).

Answer (score 3):

*Der Satz **des** Pythagoras* is a fixed term so it should be

- die Feinheiten des Satzes **des** Pythagoras

or

- die Feinheiten im Satz **des** Pythagoras

if you want to avoid the double genitive.

Comment: Satz des Pythagoras oder Satz von Pythagoras. Das macht keinen Unterschied imho (außer das 'des' etwas schöner klingt, weil es mit ein Plaisier ist, mich einer elaborierten Sprache zu befleißigen.

Comment: Shouldn't "Pythagoras-Satz" be considered a valid alternative? *Die Feinheiten des Pythagoras-Satzes ...*

Comment: @bakunin no, every native speaker of German learns about it as "Satz des/von Pythagoras" in school and will only recognize those wordings and will be confused if you say it differently

Comment: @wonderbear: in this case I should have perhaps my native speaker status revoked, because I remember my teachers using both variants. I will switch over to my native Northern-Korean SE now.

Comment: @bakunin, ich war jetzt neugierig, ob das vielleicht auch eine Generationenfrage ist, aber wenn ich einfach nach „Satz Pythagoras“ google, muss ich sehr weit nach unten scrollen, bis ich zum ersten Msl „Satz von Pythagoras“ lese. Aber das kann natürlich mündlich häufiger sein.